# Get Last six rows from a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure which gives me the raw data I require for Data Analysis.

This SP, at the minute populates a temporary table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #Analysis
(
    AgreementID int,
    DueDate datetime,
    DateFrom datetime,
    DateTo datetime,
    AmountDue decimal(9,2),
    AmountPaid decimal(9,2),
    DueTD decimal(9,2),
    PaidTD decimal (9,2),
    ArrearsScore int
)
```

AgreementID can repeat in this table between 6 records upwards.

What I need to do, is for each AgreementID, I need to Get the LAST 6 Rows

This will then allow me to carry out the rest of my analysis.

I have tried:

```
    SELECT
          AN.*
    FROM
          #Analysis AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT 
             TOP(6) * 
          FROM 
              #Analysis 
          ORDER BY 
              AgreementID, DueDate DESC
         ) AS AN ON A.AgreementID = AN.AgreementID
    WHERE AN.AgreementID IS NOT NULL
```

But this does not give me the desired results.

Can anyone advise?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `SQL Server 2005+`, you can use `Common Table Expression` and `Windowing function`. The `ROW_NUMBER()` gives a rank or value for every `AgreementID` which the record has value of 1 sorted from latest `DueDate`.

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  AgreementID,
            DueDate,
            DateFrom,
            DateToe,
            AmountDue,
            AmountPaid,
            DueTD,
            PaidTD,
            ArrearsScore,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AgreementID 
                        ORDER BY AgreementID, DueDate DESC) rn
    FROM    #Analysis
)
SELECT  AgreementID,
        DueDate,
        DateFrom,
        DateToe,
        AmountDue,
        AmountPaid,
        DueTD,
        PaidTD,
        ArrearsScore
FROM    records
WHERE   rn <= 6
```

without using `CTE`

```
SELECT  AgreementID,
        DueDate,
        DateFrom,
        DateToe,
        AmountDue,
        AmountPaid,
        DueTD,
        PaidTD,
        ArrearsScore
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  AgreementID,
                    DueDate,
                    DateFrom,
                    DateToe,
                    AmountDue,
                    AmountPaid,
                    DueTD,
                    PaidTD,
                    ArrearsScore,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AgreementID 
                                ORDER BY AgreementID, DueDate DESC) rn
            FROM    #Analysis
        ) records
WHERE   rn <= 6
```

Comment: How do I add a WITH statement to an SP, its not something I am familiar with, and it is throwing me the following error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Apologies, I read the error right, and required a semi colon BEFORE the WITH statement. Thank you

Comment: you need to add `;` before the `WITH` keyword `:)`

Comment: Hi. Can this be done as a select statement, or can I build a select statement around this in order to further analyse the result set. Thank you.

Comment: updated the answer withput using `CTE`. did the result gave what you wanted? if not, tell me what is the problem so I can modify the statement.